# How to set a timer to update API data periodically in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, timer, future

I'm getting data from an API and load it to a listview.  My listview is showing the result of the query without any problem. I want to update my listview by periodically getting data from API. What is the best way to do this?

This is how I'm calling API method in initState of Home Screen.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _fixtureData = getFixture();
  }

  Future<List<Fixtures>> getFixture() async {
    fixtureList = await FootballApi.getFixtureData();
    return fixtureList;
  }
```

This is the code which I render ListView by FutureBuilder in Home Screen.

```
              FutureBuilder<List<Fixtures>>(
                  future: _fixtureData,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      fixtureList = snapshot.data;

                      return AppListView(
                        matchList: fixtureList,
                        //callback function brings the matchCounter value from ListView class
                        onChange: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            matchCounter = value;
                          });
                        },
                        finalBetList: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            betList = value;
                          });
                        },
                      );
                    }
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          width: 60,
                          height: 60,
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                          child: Text(
                            'Awaiting result...',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

And this snippet is the API method that I call.

```
static Future<List<Fixtures>> getFixtureData() async {
    Map<String, String> queryParameters = {
      'league': '79',
      'next': '5',
    };


    http.Response response = await http.get(
      getUrl('fixtures', queryParameters),
      headers: requestHeaders,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      List<dynamic> result = jsonDecode(data)['response'];

      for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        Fixtures fixture = Fixtures();

        fixture.leagueID = jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['league']['id'];
        fixture.country = jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['league']['country'];
        fixture.leagueName = jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['league']['name'];
        fixture.fixtureID = jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['fixture']['id'];

        //get Odds to match with fixtures by fixtureID
        await getOddsData(fixture.fixtureID);

        fixture.dateTime =
            DateTime.parse(jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['fixture']['date']);
        fixture.homeTeam =
            jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['teams']['home']['name'];
        fixture.awayTeam =
            jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['teams']['away']['name'];
        fixture.status =
            jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['fixture']['status']['long'];
        fixture.homeGoals = jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['goals']['home'];
        fixture.awayGoals = jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['goals']['away'];
        fixture.htScoreHome =
            jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['score']['halftime']['home'];
        fixture.htScoreAway =
            jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['score']['halftime']['away'];
        fixture.ftScoreHome =
            jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['score']['fulltime']['home'];
        fixture.ftScoreAway =
            jsonDecode(data)['response'][i]['score']['fulltime']['away'];

        if (oddsList.length > 0) {
          for (int j = 0; j < oddsList.length; j++) {
            if (oddsList[j].fixtureID == fixture.fixtureID) {
              fixture.homeOdds = oddsList[j].homeOdds;
              fixture.drawOdds = oddsList[j].drawOdds;
              fixture.awayOdds = oddsList[j].awayOdds;
              fixture.bookmakerName = oddsList[j].bookmakerName;
              FootballApi.fixtureList.add(
                  fixture);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      print('statusCode: ' + response.statusCode.toString());
    }

    return FootballApi.fixtureList;
  }
```

Comment: you can use [Timer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html) to periodically call a function which would fetch the data and then update the `state` of the widget resulting in rebuild with new data got from the API

Answer (score 0):

A timer would be a nice choice.
Start a timer once your state is initialized and dispose of once the widget is disposed.
Inside the timer, you call the API and `setState` for the widget.

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   getFixture();
   _timer = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 30), 
   (_) => getFixture());
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   _timer.cancel();
   super.dispose();
 }
```

Comment: when I set timer in initState, it is also waiting for 30 sec to show the initial data. I want to render the listview with initial data, after tahay upate it in every 5 min for example. Where should I set the timer?

Comment: Let timer be at that place only. But before timer call getFixture()

Comment: thanks. Also, I should call getFixture in setSate to rerender screen, right? My initState code is like; void initState() {
    _fixtureData = getFixture();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 30), (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        _fixtureData = getFixture();
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }